# Developing recurrence relation for algorithm

Tags: algorithm, recurrence

I'm having difficulty developing recurrence relations for algorithms. This is the algorithm I'm given:

```
int result = silly (n);
public static int silly (int n)
{
if (n <= 1)
  {
   return -100;
  }
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
  sum += i;
  }
return sum + silly (n-2);
}
```

I understand that the base case is 
`T(1) = 1`, but do not understand what T(n) is. Would it be

```
T(n) = n[T(n-2) + 1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close to having the right recurrence, but what you have is a bit off.

Typically speaking, a recurrence relation splits the work done into two parts:

- the work done *within* a single recursive call, and
- the work done due to new recursive calls fired off.

So let's see what this function does. You're correct that the work done within a single call is O(n), due to the big for loop. So that means that we'd have something like

> T(n) = ________ + O(n)

The bit you'd fill in the blank with corresponds to the recursive calls fired off by a single function. In this case, each function call fires off one additional recursive call whose input is of size n - 2, so the recurrence would be

> T(n) = T(n - 2) + O(n)

The answer you came up with is essentially

> T(n) = nT(n - 2) + O(n)

which is close, but overcounts the number of recursive calls that end up getting made. Writing nT(n - 2) as part of the recurrence would mean that there are n different recursive calls made *from a single call*, each of which has size n - 2. That's what you'd get if, say, the recursive call was inside the for loop rather than outside it.